# Merge duplicates in list?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have list of `String`, that have a lot of **duplicates**.
I need to **merge duplicates** and count it to another list.
I know, that i can use `Map`, or smt , but then i need to `sort` that list, and i don't know, if i can sort `Map`.
 something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
        {                
            if (word.get(i).equals(itself))
            {
                //if word in list, add 1 to counter                  
                int index = (int)word_used.get(i)+1;
                word_used.set(i, index);                    
                wordscount++;
                return 0;                    
            }
else
 {
                if(i == word.size() - 1)//No matches
                {
                    //add to list
                    write_to_voc(s);                       
                    return 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can use a `TreeMap` which is sorted by key. Or you can sort the lists first and use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve insertion order. Or you can build the map, extract the entries or keys from it into a list and sort that. There are so many ways.

Comment: There is also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html. 
so many ways...

Answer (score 0):

Example with stream:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("cc", "aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "cc", "cc");
Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> 1, (i, j) -> i + j, TreeMap::new));
System.out.println(map);
```

output:

```
{aaa=2, bbb=1, cc=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the one with `Colletions.frequency`

```
List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++){   
    int occcurence = Collections.frequency(word, word.get(i));
    if(!sortedMap.containsKey(word.get(i)))
        sortedMap.put(word.get(i), occcurence);
}
System.out.println(sortedMap);
```